# Sitecore commerce 9.0.2 interface not loading

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have a admin user1 (user1 is a adminstrator) and a default admin. Now when I login using default admin user the sitecore BizFX interface loads fine but with user1 the screen shows loading symbol indefinitely. I have also assigned sitecore\commerce administrator role to the admin user1

Getting `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` message in console

Have I missed any configuration?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue was due to local self signed certificates. When I changed the certificates to real ones it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It happens if your bizfx configuration is not correct. If you go to your bizfx installation directly, under assets folder you will find config.json. Check for the url to Commerce Engine. Since Bizfx is talking to your commerce engine, most probably authoring role, you need to make sure the ssl certificates are rightly set.
here are the details of certificates in 9.x
https://sitecoredude.com/the-dudes-guide-to-certificates-in-sitecore-experience-commerce-9/

Comment: but this works for default admin user.

Comment: There are two Commerce roles, commerce admin and commerce business user. Make sure, your user has both roles assigned. Or after you assign a role, clear the cache.

Comment: I have assigned the roles but still it doesn't work